# BULK INSERT runs fine in window, but fails inside sql job

Tags: sql-server, bulk-insert

I have two server (in the same network), `Server A`, is the web server, with IIS and all, `Server B` is the second server, the DB (MS SQL Server 2012), both Windows 2012 R2.

In the `Server A`, files are uploaded to this folder, `uploaded-bills`. That I have shared with `\\web-server-01\uploaded-bills\`.

*I have given FULL ACCESS (in the security tab) to EVERYONE in that folder!*

Now, this bulk insert runs in the `SQL Server` in `Server B`

```
INSERT INTO BillDetails (
    ItemID
    ,Qty
    ,Amount
    )
SELECT ItemID
    ,Qty
    ,Amount
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\web-server-01\uploaded-bills\itemised-bill.csv', FIRSTROW = 2, FORMATFILE = 'D:\itemised-bill-format-file.fmt') AS BulkLoadFile;
```

Which runs perfectly fine. But if I create a job, to ran at a particular schedule, it *always* fails. When it is triggered automatically (due to time cycle) or I ran the job manually. When I view the history, it shows me this error:

```
The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 16 (InsertItemisedBillsEveryFiveMinutes).  The last step to run was step 1 (BulkInsert).,00:00:00,0,0,,,,0
05/29/2017 15:30:00,InvoiceUploadRawInsertJob,Error,1,SERVER-B,BillsUploadRawJob,BulkInsert,,Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Cannot bulk load because the file "\\web-server-01\uploaded-bills\itemised-bill.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4861).
```

As I mentioned, I have given everyone the whole access, even then the sql sever agent can't seem to access it. Also, I can access this folder fine in the windows explorer without any issues, and even the query executes fine when you run this query in a new query window. But for the love of Microsoft I can't figure out why the job is failing, and what should I do to fix that. Can anyone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

**Update**
Update after comment and Remus's answer.

Yes `Server A` and `Server B` are in domain, in the same domain.

The `SQL Server` service (`MSSQLSERVER`) is running under a windows account name `Expo` (in the `log on` tab in the service configuration, in `services.msc`) amd that `Expo` account is available domain, so I can log in in `Server A` as well as `Server B` using that account's credentials.

The `SQL Server Agent` is running under (in the `log on` tab in the service configuration, in `services.msc`) `NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT`.

As for `Everyone`, I grant it `Read\Write` in the file sharing dialog, under `Sharing` tab, and in the `Security` tab, I've added everyone with `Full Control` checkbox checked. (*But I am guessing the `Everyone` on `Server A` could be different from the `Everyone` on `Server B`, I could be wrong though*).

Please let me know if I could provide any more information to help sort out this.

**Update 2**
I've created the credentials and proxy, but in the job step dialog, `Job Step Properties`, the `Run as` option is disabled because the `Type` I have selected is `Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)` which is actually it's type. So, how do I specify the proxy account for this?

Comment: Who is "everyone"? All the local accounts on the local machine? The web server doesn't know who those accounts are.

Comment: Yes, `Everyone` is all local account on the `Server A`, but I guess for the accounts in `Server B`, the `Server A` is unaware of those. I've also updated the question with further details.

Comment: File shares unfortunately have _two_ security permissions settings. Usually at the _share_ level you just give `Everyone` access. But then you actually need to go into the folder (not the share) right click and and set access there.

Comment: Also I notice the path in your error message isn't the same as the one in the command line - is that a typo?

Comment: Everyone on the server with the share only includes accounts explicitly defined on that server. Local accounts on the other server are not included in that group. So you would have to use a domain account or proxy for the SQL Server Agent service, and make sure that account is explicitly granted access to the share. There are other ways too, such as Agent calling a procedure that executes as that domain account.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Yes, that was a typo. I've fixed it!

Comment: You might consider setting up a new domain service account and then setup a proxy account and use the credentials in the configuration. Grant the new domain service account `change` at the share level of the `\\server\share` and `modify` access to the `\share` folder at that level for the NTFS ACL permissions. You cannot authenticate a local machine account to a network or domain resources without special configurations so just make it a domain account with explicit permissions and setup as an SQL proxy and then tell the job to run as it's security context instead. See if BCP makes any differ~

Comment: Also, as per **`Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT.`** this means this is what is trying to access the `\\server\share` on the other machine and because `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT` is not a domain account, it cannot authenticate to the share, etc.... Thus your configuration appears to not be setup correctly for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @McDonald's virtual service accounts should access the network as the host `domain\machine$` account and that should be a member of `Everybody`

Comment: As per `Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)` this means the security configurations in this particular instance are not setup for the need regardless so this appears to be a simple access error so your security configurations are wrong as per the security context that is passed when the job is run from the SQL Agent. I never use `everyone` to grant access to any resource (let alone `FULL CONTROL`) and especially in a domain environment. I left a suggestion how I'd consider resolving it, etc.

Answer (score 3):

When you run that query interactively then SQL Server impersonates you when accessing the share. Normally this would fall into double-hop Kerberos Constrained Delegation and fail unless set up appropriately. It works because probably one of the hops is short-circuited (eg. you log on from a session on Server A or Server B).

When the query is run as a job the query impersonates the SQL Server agent service, and it all depends on how the SQL Server Agent is configured to run and connect to SQL Server. Different answers apply depending on whether the connection is made using a SQL Server login (eg. `sa`), a domain account, a virtual account, a local built-in account (eg. LocalService) and so on and so forth.

We here cannot *guess* what the problem is. To document it, please provide the details of the accounts involved. Are Server A/B in a domain? In the same domain? Is SQL Server running as a domain account, as a virtual account, as a local account, as local service, or what? Is SQL Server Agent running as who?

When you granted access to `Everyone`, did you grant access to the *share* or did you grant access to the *folder*?

Ideally you should set up an audit policy and then simply consult the event log, which will tell you exactly which account attempted the access. See [Auditing File Access on File Servers](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/08/26/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers/)

Finally, you may be interested in reading up about [SQL Server Agent proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy).

Comment: I've updated the answer, with the details you told me to share.

Comment: Pay special attention to this line: "grant access to the folder?" that's probably your problem

Comment: @Razort4x I suggest you set up audit so you can figure out what account exactly is trying to access the resource.